# BCP out Error in SQL2000: SQLState = 37000, NativeError = 4060

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, jdbc, sql-server-2000, bcp

I have created a proc that grabs all the user tables in a local DB on my machine. I want to be able to create a flat file of all my tables using BCP and SQL. Its a dummy database in SQL 2000 connecting through windows authentication. I have set my enviroment path variable in WinXP SP2. I have created new users to access the db, switched off my firewall, using trusted connection. I have tried dozens of forums, no luck.

In dos command prompt I get the same error.

SQLState = 37000, NativeError = 4060
Error = [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Cannot open database requested in login '[HelpDesk-EasyPay'. Login fails.

Here is my SP:

```
@Path VARCHAR(100),
    @UserName VARCHAR(15),
    @PassWord VARCHAR(15),
    @ServerName VARCHAR(15)
AS 

set quoted_identifier off
set nocount on

declare @n int
declare @db varchar(40)
set @db=DB_NAME()
declare @TableName varchar(15) 
declare @bcp varchar(200)
select identity(int,1,1) as tblNo,name tblname into #T from Sysobjects where xtype='u'
select @n=COUNT(*) from #T

WHILE (@n>0)
BEGIN
    SELECT @TableName=tblname FROM #T WHERE tblno=@n
    PRINT 'Now BCP out for table: ' + @TableName
    SET @bcp = "master..xp_cmdshell 'BCP " + "[" + @db + ".." + @TableName + "]" + " OUT" + @Path + "" + @TableName+".txt -c -U" + @UserName + " -P" + @PassWord + " -S" + @ServerName + " -T" + "'" 
    EXEC(@bcp)
    SET @n=@n-1
END

DROP TABLE #T
```

Can anyone advise. This seems to be a connection problem or BCP ? Not sure.

edit: I am running this from query analyzer because I have 118 tables to output to flat file. I seem to agree that its an authentication issue because I tried connecting to master db with username sa password root. which is what its set to and I get the same error: SQLState = 37000, NativeError = 4060

Comment: What is the command line string you are using to run this? This looks like an authentication issue.

Comment: I am running this from query analyzer because I have 118 tables to output to flat file. I seem to agree that its an authentication issue because I tried connecting to master db with username sa password root. which is what its set to and I get the same error: SQLState = 37000, NativeError = 4060 If I run it from the command line, same error. It must be something small that I am missing ?

Comment: Also I believe you want "queryout" not "out"

Answer (score 1):

Your brackets are extending over the entire qualified table name - only the individual components should be bracketed:

```
bcp [HelpDesk-EasyPay].dbo.[customer] out d:\MSSQL\Data\customer.bcp -N -Utest -Ptest -T
```

should work, so you want:

```
SET @bcp = "master..xp_cmdshell 'BCP " + "[" + @db + "]..[" + @TableName + "]" + " OUT" + @Path + "" + @TableName+".txt -c -U" + @UserName + " -P" + @PassWord + " -S" + @ServerName + " -T" + "'"
```

in your code.  It looks like the error message you gave was truncated, otherwise you would have been able to see that it was attempting to open database "[HelpDesk-EasyPay.dbo.customer]" which, of course, does not exist, and even if it did, you would then get an error that no table was specified.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue for the OUT (the minus character kills everything event the ^ don't work)

I avoid it with the QUERYOUT. Like this :

```
SET  @s = 'BCP "SELECT * FROM [HelpDesk-EasyPay].dbo.customers" QUERYOUT myfile.txt ...'
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe someone will come in handy: I have the same issue with SQL Server 2017. The reason was the square brackets around the database name.